# error with hibernate update property

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am very new to hibernate and java

I am working on an assignment and everything was working fine but then the teacher asked me to change

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

and now I am receiving the following error after the first attempt to write on the Database,

**org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService**

**INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory**

I am really not sure what is the problem and how to fix it, I know that create is used to create the tables if they are not already created before and that update only update the already exists tables. But i am not sure why I am getting this problem.

I am using hibernate with mysql on Mac

Comment: It's an information log. Not an error log. Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: @JBNizet my program actually read a text file and enter some data from it into the DB, when I set the Hibernate conf to "Create" it go through the whole file but now when I use "Update" it stops after the first one and it gives me that message, that is why I assumed that it is an error, I can imagine that this might sounds ver tedious , but I am very new to all this